# How to pass a literal variable reference (${foo}) as program argument in a run configuration

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, when you specify arguments in the run dialog, Eclipse interprets `${foo}` as a request to use the Eclipse variable *foo*.  I would like to pass a string to my application that contains `${foo}` but Eclipse treats this as an undefined variable and gives me an error.

```
 -Dfoo "bar" --pattern "regex magic ${foo}"
```

Eclipse does not accept the single quote (') as a quoting character, instead it becomes part of the input.  Does anyone know how I can escape `${foo}` in this dialog so it is interpreted as text and not a variable reference?

Comment: Have you tried navigating to the "Environment" tab in the Run Configurations Window and then pressing "Select" and selecting the Environment variable?

Comment: I don't want to set a variable, I want to escape text so Eclipse passes it as a string instead of replacing it with the "variable"'s contents.  It might work to set the variable ${foo} to "${foo}" however...

Comment: I'm looking for an answer that escapes ${foo} when it is in double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define a variable in Eclipse:
name = dollar, value = $

(This can be done in the "run configuration" dialog, when you type your arguments, click "Variables...", and then click "Edit variables...", and add that variable).

Then, in the arguments text-box, type
${dollar}"{foo}"

Answer (score 17):

${foo} by itself can be escaped with $"{foo}".

When ${foo} is already part of a doubly-quoted string, as in your question, I'm not sure how or if it can be escaped.

Comment: This worked for me. I created a run configuration for maven and I was able to add this: `exec.workdir -> target/$"project.build.finalName"` in the argument list. 
But I was not able to use the same syntax in the "Base directory" field.

Comment: Escaping as `$"{"` seems to work both in quoted and unquoted args, at least on Windows

Answer (score 11):

I do not think there is any way to do this in Eclipse.

The offending bit of code is [org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.StringSubstitutionEngine#substitute](http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/IDE-Eclipse/core/org/eclipse/core/internal/variables/StringSubstitutionEngine.java.htm).

This is the bit of code that substitutes the ${foo} with whatever you've defined foo to be. Unfortunately, it can cope with nested and concatenated variables, so if dollar="$" and rest="{foo}" then ${dollar}${rest} gives ${foo} which gets evaluated again.

For info, in the code reportUndefinedVariables is hardcoded as true further up the stack, which is why you're getting the error message. There doesn't seem to be any way of changing it.

Comment: Open bug ticket: [Bug 336868 - No mechanism to escape ${...} from variable substitution](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=336868)

Comment: Not sure if a coincidence.. but typing `$foo` resulted in `oo`. Typing `$$foo` resulted in `$foo` (which is what I intended).