# Disabling eclipse command line argument variable substitution

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I have a java application that takes command line arguments passed to it in eclipse. I want to pass the app an argument that contains the string "${*something*}," but eclipse sees this and tries to substitute a variable for it. Since the variable doesn't exist, eclipse refuses to launch with a "Reference to undefined variable " error.

Is it possible to have eclipse ignore a certain variable for substitution, or is there a way I can escape this argument so that eclipse ignores it?

I've tried:

- Escaping the $ with a \ (no effect)
- Escaping the $ as a double $$ (no effect)
- Using $\{\} (passes the \'s through as literals)
- Setting the value of the eclipse variable ${*something*} to ${*something*} (no effect, it seems eclipse respects recursion here)

Comment: The solution is described [there][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801753/escape-variable-in-eclipse-run-args/5105120#5105120