# Invalid command arguments to Java program

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to pass the following Application argument:

```
${Y}
```

but Eclipse gives an error:

[image]

I'm using Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: where is the value of Y defined?  Is it an env var? What if you pass a plain value?

Comment: it's not a env var, it's supposed to be a simple string

Comment: I don't want eclipse to resolve this argument, simply evaluate it as a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a literal variable reference (${foo}) as program argument in a run configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801753/how-to-pass-a-literal-variable-reference-foo-as-program-argument-in-a-run-c)

Answer (score 0):

The right way to escape it is:

```
$"{Y}"
```

Hopes it helps somebody...